# PDO Storing Array using Memcache

Tags: php, pdo, memcached

I'm trying to store an array in the cache, however I'm getting the error:

> md5() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in

Here's the code:

```
function getList(){
        global $meminstance;

        $query = $this->connection->prepare("SELECT id FROM " . TBL_LIST . " ORDER BY name");
        $query_key = "KEY" . md5($query);
        $list = $meminstance->get($query_key);

        if (!$list){
            $query = $this->connection->query("SELECT id FROM " . TBL_LIST . " ORDER BY name");
            $list = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
            $meminstance->set($query_key, $list, 0, 600);
        }
        return $list;
    }
```

What does the error mean? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the error message has nothing to do heither with pdo nor with memcache

Comment: What does it have to do with? It says it it's on the line of `$query_key = "KEY" . md5($query);`

Comment: with MD5. It expects a string

Comment: @YourCommonSense So what can I do? I'm confused here. I used the above on other memcache items but never got the error. Is it because I'm holding onto an array of info?

Comment: Do you have the code that works **without** any caching? it seems you don't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You trying to md5 object instead of string. Also there is nothing to prepare.

Try this.

```
function getList(){
        global $meminstance;

        $sql = "SELECT id FROM " . TBL_LIST . " ORDER BY name";
        $query_key = "KEY" . md5($sql);
        $list = $meminstance->get($query_key);

        if (!$list){
            $query = $this->connection->query($sql);
            $list = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $meminstance->set($query_key, $list, 0, 600);
        }
        return $list;
    }
```

Comment: Errors gone but now I can't see the data returned from the query.

Comment: I do not know value of TBL_LIST, also i don not know data of your DB/